# "isNaN(INFINITY)==false" is false

Tags: java, c++, .net, nan, infinity

Infinity is not a number in any standard math, which would lead one to think the expression

```
Double.isNaN(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
```

should evaluate to `true`. However, a quick test reveals that it evaluates to `false`. A closer look at the function specification confirms my suspicions: "isNaN" is not to be interpreted as "is not a number", but as "is a Not-a-Number value".

My question is why did they implement it as such? Why didn't they implement it in such a way that it would also return `false` for either positive or negative infinity?

In practice I now use `(Double.isNaN(x) || Double.isInfinite(x))` way more often than I only use `Double.isNaN(x)`. Therefore it would have been better to use `Double.isNaN(x)` and `(Double.isNaN(x) && !Double.isInfinite(x))` respectively instead.

Even though changing it now would be confusing - wouldn't it have been better to have implemented and explained the function in the way I have here described?

What other considerations play a role here?

PS: please omit any remark on the law of the excluded middle. ;)

Comment: Why is this tagged as `C++`?

Comment: But in certain sets, infinity is considered a number, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line.  Furthermore, in IEEE maths, infinities at least obey inequality comparisons (`<`, `>`, etc.), unlike `NaN`.

Comment: Is it any different in `C++` then?

Comment: I think that ““isNaN(INFINITY)==false” is false” needs another negation.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: you're saying that '“isNaN(INFINITY)==false” is false' is false? I think it's false that you're wrong.

Comment: @Manu343726 True, the code is not c++, but the question is applying to an infinite number of programming languages (essentially)

Answer (score 9):

Dr. William Kahan has numerous pieces out there explaining his thoughts behind the decisions in [IEEE-754.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

- Lecture notes covering the rationale:  http://www.laputan.org/pub/papers/ieee754.pdf
- Papers at his web page here:  http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/
- And if you're curious of the history, an interview here:  http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/754story.html

I suggest you read his works to understand the reasoning.  He was one of the major forces behind IEEE-754, so best get the answer from the horse's mouth.

BTW, in the very technical sense, +/-Inf are numbers in the [affinely extended real number system.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinely_extended_real_number_system)  So, for that reason alone I would expect isNaN to return false on an infinity.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) `isFinite`, a function that returns `false` on infinities and NaN. It would have been confusing to call this function or its negation along the lines of `isNaN` for obvious reasons (a good practice is to avoid needless negations in names, so that the `isnotanumber` function you are thinking of would be better named `isanumber`. This function exists and it is called `isFinite`).

Comment: I like your positive contribution and constructive feedback. It would have been nice if it was already present in the `Double` package of Java...

Comment: @TimKuipers According to this blog post (original German: http://www.tutego.de/blog/javainsel/2011/10/java-8-doublefloat-isfinite-math-nextdown/ Google translate: http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.tutego.de/blog/javainsel/2011/10/java-8-doublefloat-isfinite-math-nextdown/&prev=/search%3Fq%3DisFinite%2Bjava%26safe%3Doff%26client%3Dsafari%26rls%3Den%26biw%3D1076%26bih%3D694 ) isFinite should be part of Java 8.

Comment: I can't wait for Java 8! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. If you look at advanced math infinity is typically treated as a number. For example, in complex analysis it is typically *1+0i* (depending on the projection chosen it may be a different value). That is, it is perfectly sensible that IEEE 754 defined infinity no to be a NaN. NaN is used where mathematical expressions are undefined, e.g. for infinity times 0.

Comment: In that case the proper name of 'NaN' would be 'Undefined' or something the like.